# How to enable HTML in sendPhoto?

Tags: chatbot, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

```
const html = `<b>something</b>`

      bot.sendPhoto(chatId, picture, {
         caption: html,
         parse_mode: 'HTML'
})
```

Its half working - tags doesnt appear in text but also doesnt do anything.
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine, im just blind)
In the night mode bold and normal text looks very similar.